# How to create a JSLint ignore comment block in the Notepad++ plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, notepad++, jslint

I've been trying many different variations and starting to get really confused between the JavaScript Lint and JSLint suggested parameters.

All I want to do, is ignore code in the "linting" process between a 'start' and 'end' block. Something like:

```
/*jslint ignore start */
var initializing = false,
    fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
/*jslint ignore end */
```

But this unfortunately triggers this JSLint error in the Notepad++ console:

**Unexpected 'ignore'.**

What's the proper way of writing the ignore code block for the JSLint plugin in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ignore syntax like you suggest, but what you can do is to modify individual jslint settings on a temporary basis.

For example:

> ```
> /*jslint sloppy:true*/
> ...
> /*jslint sloppy:false*/
> ```